# AWSS3TransferUtility uploadFile fails due to file not found

Tags: amazon-s3, ios9, file-transfer, aws-sdk, ios9.2

I'm running the Amazon AWSS3 iOS SDK version 2.3.2 and successfully implemented file uploading and downloading using the AWSS3TransferUtility. At some point during the last few weeks we began experiencing failures. If I attempt to upload a previously saved file from my documents directory called:

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F505C2A6-3CA3-47F4-87A1-3FD2CFDE932D/Documents/1098/1098.png

the uploadFile method reports the following:

Cannot read file at file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F505C2A6-3CA3-47F4-87A1-3FD2CFDE932D/Documents/1098/1098.png

If I attempt to use the uploadData method instead of uploadFile I receive the following error:

Cannot read file at file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/652CAEA4-9174-4408-AFFD-760B275FAB5B/tmp/ea3d80e0cfabcedbe25cc9403ef3bca5/84B78171-E4CA-4F02-9297-F30756657B14-4889-00000AB32D416253.tmp

The problem appears to be with the uploadFile and uploadData methods looking for a file beginning with "///".

I researched that and found the following post reported a short time ago which includes the same scenario: Failure to read a file previously saved to the documents directory.

[Can't read saved file from documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536454/cant-read-saved-file-from-documents-directory)

Each time I retrieve the file data for the uploadData method, or retrieve the file path for the filelUpload method, I re-query the documents directory as follows:

```
- (NSString*) getDocumentsDirectory {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docsDirectory];
if (!exists) {
    NSError *error;
    exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:docsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    if (exists)
        return docsDirectory;
}
else {
    return docsDirectory;
}

return nil;
```

}

Suggestions?

Comment: The actual error I'm encountering is Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}. The AWS implementation uses NSURLSession and this now is beginning to look like the Xcode bug reported here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20919

Comment: Intended to say the AWSS3 implementation uses NSURLSessionUploadTask and NSURLSessionDownloadTask. This has been a problem apparently since Xcode 7.1 beta 3